# Where is the Shader Designer in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, shaders

I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and I've been trying to access the Shader Designer. I searched through MSDN's text and Channel9's videos, but they keep failing to mention how to access it.

Can someone let me know where it is?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315733.aspx

Comment: @Toni, you should add this as an answer

Comment: I'm not sure it qualifies as one. I don't actually have the ultimate version and don't have the functionality. Just assumed that it's integrated in the IDE and that following the getting started would help.

Comment: I found it. MS needs a facelift of documentation/tutorial/UI of their website... It's the .dgsl file that you have to create that allows you to visually create shaders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like any of the other designers in Visual Studio, you actually have to have a file of the appropriate type in your solution, and then the designer will launch every time you double-click on the file (or until you change the designer association for that file type).

For the shader designer, the file type is `.dgsl`. Simply add an existing `.dgsl` file or add a new one (the template should be under the "Graphics" sidebar heading in the Add New Item dialog), and open it and the designer will fill the main view.

More information can be found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).